# Librería sympy: Tengo el error Intel MKL FATAL ERROR: Cannot load mkl_intel_thread.dll

Tags: python, sympy

Verdaderamente ya estoy frustrado y no le encuentro solución, vean que estoy tratando de usar la libreria sympy de Python, pero al tratar de escribir código para que este me devuelva la gráfica de una función me devuelve el siguiente error: Intel MKL FATAL ERROR: Cannot load mkl_intel_thread.dll.

Lo que estoy haciendo es lo siguiente:

```py
from sympy import *
x,y,z = symbols("x y z")
print(plot(cos(x)))
```

Luego de hacer ese codigo tan sencillo para mostrar la gráfica de cos(x)
obtengo en la salida el siguiente error:

```
INTEL MKL ERROR: %1 no es una aplicaci¾n Win32 vßlida. mkl_intel_thread.dll.
Intel MKL FATAL ERROR: Cannot load mkl_intel_thread.dll.
```

Anexo también que este error se presenta solo a la hora de gráficar, todo lo demás funciona correctamente. Lo único que se me ocurre hasta ahora es que el error sea debido al procesador ya que mi procesador es AMD y el dll que intenta ejecutar mi editor de código hace referencia a nucleos de un procesador intel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al final encontré la solución en un foro de la documentación de anaconda, estaba en inglés pero fue fácil comprenderlo. Dejaré la solución por aquí por si alguien tiene el mismo problema.

1 - Lo primero es tener Python INSTALADO CON ANACONDA, si descargaste Python desde su página oficial debes borrarlo y descargar anaconda e instalarla para que instale Python.

2 - Abrir la cmd y escribir el siguiente comando `set CONDA_DLL_SEARCH_MODIFICATION_ENABLE=1`

3 - Dirígete a la carpeta System32 en C:\Windows\System32 y busca los siguientes archivos:

```
mkl_intel_thread.dll
libiomp5md.dll
```

4 - Dichos archivos hay que cambiarles su extensión .dll por la extension .bak quedando:

```
mkl_intel_thread.bak
libiomp5md.bak
```

5 - Paso opcional, solo para quienes tengan sistema de 64bits. Deben dirigirse a la carpeta SysWOW64 en C:\Windows\SysWOW64 y cambiar la extensión de los mismos archivos anteriores a .bak.

6 - En caso de que el problema persista buscar los siguientes archivos y repetir los pasos 4 y 5:

```
 mkl_core.dll
 mkl_def.dll
```

Con esto el problema ya debería de estar resuelto, a mi en lo personal me lo resolvió luego de estarme partiendo la cabeza por días.